# OS-9 Programming in C

Tags: c, concurrency

I have some work to do on the OS-9 platform in C for a college assignment. Problem is, I can only do this work in my project lab. I tend to work better at home, so here's my question. Is there any way of virtualizing an OS-9 environment at home?

I realize OS-9 is proprietary, so I'm guessing I'll have to pay to do this (which I can't, but I'll satisfy my curiosity).

Any information on OS-9 and 'Ultra C', as I think it's called, would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Is there a way to ssh to OS/9 machines at school and work from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is an OS/9 emulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/os9exec/) for Mac, Windows, and Linux -- that certainly sounds promising.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I need a working OS/9 image to use the emulator. :(